# Flutter audioplayers triggers onComplete event before the track is actually completed

Tags: flutter

I am trying to achieve a direct task, I want to autoplay the next track after the current track finishes, but sometimes the onComplete event is triggered before even the track is completed which lead to skip one of the tracks

the package I am using is: audioplayers ^0.14.2
the tracks are fetched from the database they are not local tracks

```
  void play(List<SoundTrack> tracks){


    audioPlayer.play(tracks[currentIndex].url);
    setIsTalking = true;

      audioPlayer.onPlayerCompletion.listen((event) {
        if(currentIndex < tracks.length-1) {
          next(tracks);
        } else {
          audioPlayer.release();
          setIsTalking = false;
          setPlayerState = PlayerState.paused;
        }
        print('completed this track, current index is' + currentIndex.toString());

      });




  }
```

````
  void next(List<SoundTrack> tracks){

    setCurrentIndex = currentIndex +1;
    play(tracks);
  }```
````

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

define

```
int currentIndex = 0;
```

and

```
  play(List<String> urlList, int currentIndex) async {
    int result = await audioPlayer.play(urlList[currentIndex]);
    if (result == 1) {
      print('Success: is playing');
    } else {
      print('Error on audio play');
    }

    audioPlayer.onPlayerCompletion.listen((event) {
      if(currentIndex < urlList.length-1){
        currentIndex = currentIndex + 1;
        nextTrack(urlList, currentIndex);
        print("NEXT AUDIO! $currentIndex");
      } else {
        print("AUDIO COMPLETED PLAYING");
      }
    });
  }


  void nextTrack(List<String> urlList, int currentIndex) {
    play(urlList, currentIndex);
  }
```

In your play botton you call

```
nextTrack(urlList, currentIndex)
```

I tested and for me it is working.